# Need a regex to match either an integer or a quoted-string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out a regex to validate what follows one of (<, >, =, !=) to insure that it is either an integer or a single-quoted-string (possible with spaces).

Some examples:

```
SELECT * WHERE field1=5      // OK
SELECT * WHERE field1=   5   // OK
SELECT * WHERE field1<   -2  // OK
SELECT * WHERE field1='5'    // OK
SELECT * WHERE field1=a      // NOT OK - a is not an integer
SELECT * WHERE field1!='a'   // OK
SELECT * WHERE field1='a     // NOT OK - missing closing quote

EDIT:  I forgot to add it should work with multiple fields such as
SELECT * WHERE field1=5 AND field2=b  // NOT OK since field2 following is not a int
SELECT * WHERE field1=5 AND (field1<6 AND fieldb='a')  // OK
```

Comment: Ok, and your attempts...

Comment: You need to ask a question (and any effort you made to solve it) - rather than put up your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
.*(=|<|>|!=)\s*(-?\d+|'[^']+')
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rX1pW3/1)

Comment: this is great, thanks though i forgot to mention there may be multiple fields separated with AND, OR, (, )   (brackets and AND/OR)